# How to create a multidimensional ForEach loop in php using openSUSE vim editor

Tags: php, foreach, wsdl

I am having trouble creating a ForEach loop to get stock prices from the wsdl file. I attached a screenshot of my code and output.  Please advise.

[image: output and code screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please enter code directly in your question. It's easier to understand and comment if needed.

Comment: Please include your code as text in the question rather than as an image. Please elaborate on what you mean by "having trouble". What is supposed to happen? What is happening instead?

Comment: I guess you're only seeing the price for IBM now (even if the output is Apple, IBM etc) ?

Comment: Not as a screenshot. As TEXT. You have to type it manually. You could just copy rustyjim's code and add some original code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should paste the code, but I made something anyway.

```
<?php
$url_soap = "url_here";
$client = new SoapClient($url_soap);
$list = array("ibm", "microsoft", "apple", "mcdonald's");
foreach($list as $name){
    $price = $client->getQuote($name);
    echo strtoupper($name)."   ".$price."<br />";
}
```

You get the price for every item this way.

Comment: I figured OP meant this, but I was to lazy to type the code manually :-)

Comment: Hope it helps :) But if it helps OP, please edit question post with the real code.